# Batch File: Need conditional script that would log out any user apart for me

Tags: windows, batch-file, authentication, logout, winlogon

I am looking for some help.
I am looking to create a local logon script on Local GPO on my desktop.
What I need to do is, when any user logs in, this script will fire and check the currently logged in user, and if it's not my account then it would logoff.

Something like:

```
IF NOT %username% = Domain\me shutdown.exe -l
```

Any other solutions also accepted.

Comment: i just need a script. since i am not from development background, i am struggling there

Comment: I'm afraid you've come to the wrong place then.. If you do some research and give it a go yourself first then we'll be more than happy to help you out. No one's going to do it all for you though.

Comment: You want to put the script on your local session? I don't get it. Why you don't just disable the accounts that have access on your machine?

Comment: I am struggling at syntax at this point of time as i said.
I did my initial research and came up with this script, but its failing with error

C:\>test.bat
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

IF not %username% EQU xxxx
shutdown.exe -l
else
echo Welcome

Comment: @Paul, sadly i cant, i am not domain admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's you are looking is `HELP IF`

The syntax should look like:

```
@echo off

rem add your username here after the = without space.
set "_MyUsername=MyUsername"

if [%username%] neq [%_MyUsername%] shutdown.exe /l /f || exit /b 0
```